# Drupal autocomplete fails to pull out data as a subdomain

Tags: drupal-6

I managed to pull out data using autocomplete at my local (http://mysite.dev/swan/autocomplete). The json data is displayed.

But when I applied the same module at live (now a subdomain: http://test.mysite.com/swan/autocomplete with different drupal installs), this autocomplete fails to pull out data. No json data is displayed.

Do you have any idea if this is related to cross domain issue, or any possible cause I might not be aware of?

This is the callback:

```
/**
 * Callback to allow autocomplete of organisation profile text fields.
 */
function swan_autocomplete($string) {
  $matches = array();
  $result = db_query("SELECT nid, title FROM {node} WHERE status = 1 AND type='organisation' AND title LIKE LOWER ('%s%%')", $string, 0, 40);
  while ($obj = db_fetch_object($result)) {
    $title = check_plain($obj->title);
    //$matches[$obj->nid] = $title;
    $matches[$title] = $title;
  }
  //drupal_json($matches); // fails at safari for first timers
  print drupal_to_js($matches);
  exit();
}
```

Any hint would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the conflict with password_policy.module. Other similar modules just do the same blocking. These modules stop any autocomplete query.